# How to display an array of data in python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display the data of this array in django:
[('abdo', 'daou', 'charbel', 'hankach', datetime.date(2021, 5, 19), 40000, 30000, 10000),('abdo', 'daou', 'charbel', 'hankach', datetime.date(2021, 5, 19), 40000, 30000, 10000)]

This array is given by this python code:

```
def getConsultations(request):
    con=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="djangohospital")
    mycursor=con.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(some query)
    res=mycursor.fetchall()
    print(res)
```

return render(request,'consultations.html',{'consultations':res})

The sql query is:

```
select
  (
    select
      firstname
    from
      hospitalmanagementwebsite_doctors
    where
      hospitalmanagementwebsite_doctors.id = hospitalmanagementwebsite_consultations.doctor_id_id
  ) as doctor_firstname,
  (
    select
      lastname
    from
      hospitalmanagementwebsite_doctors
    where
      hospitalmanagementwebsite_doctors.id = hospitalmanagementwebsite_consultations.doctor_id_id
  ) as doctor_lastname,
  (
    select
      firstname
    from
      hospitalmanagementwebsite_patients
    where
      hospitalmanagementwebsite_patients.id = hospitalmanagementwebsite_consultations.patient_id_id
  ) as patient_firstname,
  (
    select
      lastname
    from
      hospitalmanagementwebsite_patients
    where
      hospitalmanagementwebsite_patients.id = hospitalmanagementwebsite_consultations.patient_id_id
  ) as patient_lastname,
  consultation_date,
  total,
  paid,
  leftt
from
  hospitalmanagementwebsite_consultations
```

I want to display these data in html,and i am trying it like this:

```
{% for cons in consultations %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{cons[0]}} {{cons[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{cons[2]}} {{cons[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{cons[4]}}</td>
        <td>{{cons[5]}}</td>
        <td>{{cons[6]}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/editdoctor/{{doctor.id}}"><span class="btn btn-success">Edit</span></a>
            <a href="/deletedoctor/{{doctor.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

        </td>           
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

but it is giving me this error:
Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'cons[0]'

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't use the ORM? Also instead of making those subqueries again and again why don't you simply make a JOIN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a different syntax in the template:

```
<td>{{cons.0}} {{cons.1}}</td>
```